# Find Record from Array Field In PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

TableName : NameYear

This is my Table

```
ID name min_max_year
1  xyz  [1970,1971...2014]
2  abc  [1980,1981...2014]
2  pqr  [2000,2001...2014]
```

Now I want to find records that MinMaxYear include 1980.

Than How Can I do?

I try this way : NameYear.where("min_max_year IN (?)", 1980)

but getting this error :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
LINE 1: ...ROM "name_year"  WHERE (min_max_year IN (1980))
```

Comment: Try giving like this `NameYear.where("min_max_year IN (?)", [1980])`

Comment: What is a type of min_max_year column? What exactly does it contain?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `ANY` clause on the array column:

```
SELECT * FROM NameYear
WHERE 1980 = ANY(min_max_year);
```

The ActiveRecord statement would be:

```
NameYear.where("? = ANY(min_max_year)", 1980)
```

This selects any record whose `min_max_year` column contains a value of 1980.

Comment: Getting : ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side

Comment: What exactly is the type of min_max_year? In your question you suggest it is an array, but PG thinks it is something else. Do you take the array out of a table with an `int[]` definition, or do you construct it manually, in which case you probably have the quotation wrong seeing that your first error is an operator mismatch.

Comment: I take serialize :min_max_year in my model

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. What is the **exact** output when you select min_max_year, so without doing the `ANY` clause?